# Read txt file into list where each list element is delimited by row ending with colon

Tags: r

I've got  the following .txt structure

```r
test <- "A n/a:
  4001
Exam date:
  2020-01-01 15:38
Pos (deg):
18.19
18.37"
```

I'd like to read this into a list, where each list element is given the name of the row ending with a colon, and the values are given by the following rows. (see: expected output).

**Challenges**
The number of rows (the length of each list element) can differ. There can be special characters  (e.g., "A n/a") and there is the date time value which contains a pesky colon.

**My problem**

My current solution (**see below**) is unsafe, because I cannot be sure that I have a full list of all expected elements - the file might contain unexpected list elements which I would then not capture, or worse, they would mess up the entire data.

**What I tried**

- I tried reading the txt to json with `jsonlite::fromJson`, because the structure somehow resembled it, but this gave an error about an unexpected character.
- I tried to read into a single string and split, but this leaves me, again, with all values in a single list element:

```
readr::read_file(test)
strsplit(test, split = ":\n")
```

- **My current approach** is to read this in with read.csv2 and generate a lookup on the (expected) row names, create a vector for splitting and using the first element of the resulting list for naming.

```r
myfile <- read.csv2(text = test,
          header = FALSE)
lu <- paste(c("A n", "date", "Pos"), collapse = "|")

ls_file <- split(myfile$V1, cumsum(grepl(lu, myfile$V1, ignore.case = TRUE)))
names(ls_file) <- unlist(lapply(ls_file, function(x) x[1]))
ls_file <- lapply(ls_file, function(x) x <- x[2:length(x)])

## expected output is a named list 
## The spaces and backticks below do not really bother me,
## but I would get rid of them in a next step. 

ls_file
#> $`A n/a:`
#> [1] "  4001"
#> 
#> $`Exam date:`
#> [1] "  2020-01-01 15:38"
#> 
#> $`Pos (deg):`
#> [1] "18.19" "18.37"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the name of each element ends with `:`, then we can:

```
res <- readLines(textConnection(test))
res <- split(res, cumsum(endsWith(res, ':')))
res <- setNames(lapply(res, `[`, -1), sapply(res, `[`, 1))
# > res
# $`A n/a:`
# [1] "  4001"
# 
# $`Exam date:`
# [1] "  2020-01-01 15:38"
# 
# $`Pos (deg):`
# [1] "18.19" "18.37"
```

Comment: endsWith is really nice, I didn't know it. It looks like magic to me that it ignores the inline ":" setNames with the elegant call to `[` is of course much nicer than my poor code. Thanks!